# Execute Prolog program with output apart from true/false

Tags: prolog, genetic-algorithm, execution, evolutionary-algorithm, rosetta-code

I am trying to execute the example code from RosettaCode's take on writing an evolutionary algorithm in Prolog (see [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm#Prolog)).

Can anybody tell me how to generate the same output as displayed below the code example?

Comment: I don't get exactly the same output, but if you start Prolog with `swipl --traditional` then it runs. The problem is that quotation marks used to mean list of chars, but now it apparently means something else.

Comment: What have you tried and what specific issue are you encountering?

Comment: I tried executing the `time(weasel).` line in the swipl-environment and it told me, it threw a type error (expected: List, found: string) in line 13.

This could be solved by either starting Prolog the way @TomasBy suggested or by replacing all quotation marks in the code with backquotes/graves (`). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the interpretation of quotation marks in newer SWI Prolog versions (> 7.x).

Two solutions:

1. Start Prolog with `swipl --traditional`
2. Replace all quotation marks in the code with backquotes (`)

Thank you [Thomas By](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7131301/tomas-by) for your help!